# перенос на сервер чата

Tags: php, javascript, администрирование

доброго

Есть чатик, пример которого скачал. Чатик локально работает отлично. Запускаю server.php (вкладка 1). Страница с которым ничего не отображает, просто бесконечно грузится. Клиентом вызываю серверный скрипт (вкладка 2,3.. и т.д.). Локально все решается отдельными вкладками

```
var wsUri = "ws://localhost:9000/server.php";
websocket = new WebSocket(wsUri);
```

А как запустить server.php на сервере?

Comment: Добрый день. С помощью SSH, но скрипт не будет работать вечно.

Comment: А работает бесконечно? Вроде лимит времени скрипта на обычном веб-хостинге нельзя убрать

Comment: на обычном нет, поэтому читаю сейчас про VDS/VPS и прочие

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Добрый день. С помощью SSH, но скрипт не будет работать вечно на обычном веб-хостинге.